# Bigquery Free Trial limitations

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using google bigquery by Free Trial account to analyze my big data solution now. I have realized there is a limitation on numbers of project I can enable my billing setting(10 projects, for the 11th project I fail to enable my billing setting so that I am not able to create table and upload the data). I have searched online and did not find any documentation to provide the limitation number of projects/datasets/tables I can have within one account. What I have got is only the limitations on query size/times, load data size/times,table size etc. Is this only for Free Trial account? Anyone know if google bigquery have limitations on projects/dataset/table? Thanks a lot for any helps here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got answer from google engineer, the Free Trial has limit number(10) on billing  projects. Another limitation I have got so far is the I can only have 8 cores on VMs. Besides those, they do not have limitation on datasets/tables.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one limit that I know of in terms of projects : one single account cannot have more than 25 free projects.

I was not aware that you can only have 10 projects under a Free Trial billing account. I can tell you that you can have more than 10 projects if billing (not the free trial) is enabled on them.

There is no limit for tables or dataset, as long as you're willing to pay for the storage fees.